# hola tengo este codigo y no se porque me tira este error , cuando ingreso el dos! ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python

```
def mostrar(lista):
 print(lista[0],"|",lista[1],"|",lista[2])
 print(lista[3],"|", lista[4], "|",lista[5])
 print(lista[6],"|", lista[7], "|",lista[8])
def dipCasilla(pos,lista,jugador):
 if ingresarMovimiento(pos,lista,jugador)==False:
     pos=int(input("ingrese movimiento valido"))
     dipCasilla(pos,lista,jugador)
 else:
     ingresarMovimiento(pos,lista,jugador)


def llenarTablero():
lista=[]
for i in range(0,9):
    lista+="*"
return lista


def ingresarMovimiento(pos,lista,jugador):
if lista[pos]=="*":
    lista[pos]=jugador
    return lista

else:
    return False


lista=llenarTablero()
dipCasilla(2,lista,"#")
mostrar(lista)
dipCasilla(2,lista,"#")
mostrar(lista)
```

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar la traza completa del error o al menos la línea en la que ocurre el error? Supongo que en el input pero no veo forma de que eso ocurra si ingresas `2` y nada más...

Comment: El código no tira error cuando se pone 2. Lo que hace es que vuelve a preguntar "ingrese movimiento valido". Lo más probable es que tengas problemas con la indentación. Acuérdate que python es un lenguaje que no tiene llaves para anidar instrucciones, si no que lo hace con indentación. Solo un espacio innecesario de más antes o después de una línea y se daña todo.